# C++ automatic way to make truncations print an error at runtime

Tags: c++, truncation

I have just joined a team that has thousands of lines of code like:

```
int x = 0; 
x=something(); 
short y=x; 
doSomethingImportantWith(y);
```

The compiler gives nice warnings saying: Conversion of XX bit type value to "short" causes truncation. I've been told that there are no cases where truncation really happens, but I seriously doubt it.

Is there a nice way to insert checks into each case having the effect of:

```
if (x>short.max) printNastyError(__FILE,__LINE);
```

before each assignment? Doing this manually will take more time and effort than I'd like to use, and writing a script that reads the warnings and adds this stuff to the correct file as well as the required includes seems overkill -- especially since I expect someone has already done this (or something like it).

I don't care about performance (really) or anything other than knowing when these problems occur so I can either fix only the ones that really matter, or so I can convince management that it's a problem.

Comment: Why not compile with warnings as errors?

Comment: @DanF Then nobody could work on their own problems -- I'd like a debug build that does this without forcing me to fix them all now -- just so I can find the big problems.

Comment: Any check on the value would have to happen at runtime.

Comment: @DanF Yes, I'd like the compiler (or some other tool) to add in that runtime check for me. I don't think this is a technically difficult problem, and could be very useful, but it's not practical for me to put all the runtime checks in myself (we have millions of lines of code with this all over the place).

Comment: @Dale why not just run a CUnit test on it, and then show them how the code actually sucks?

Comment: @Aniket Q: Why not just say: we have 175000 warnings? A: Tried that, didn't work.

Comment: @Dale, the compiler cannot insert lines of code to do that for you .. you might have to just insert them manually. Or write a script that does that for you.. sigh

Comment: @Aniket I was hoping someone had written some nice way to do that it's more of a pain than I'd like to do to write something that reads logs and modifies the code that works %100 of the time.

Comment: @Dale there, is a way.. but I am not too sure you'd tread on that path.. creating your own C runtime with bounds checking - its just an idea in my head. Faint at the moment

Comment: `#define short MyVerySmartNumericWrapper<short>` etc. Creating `MyVerySmartNumericWrapper` is left as a painful exercise for the reader.

Comment: Honestly, this ranks closely with a "What is the bad-pattern of code like this...." question. Yeah, that pattern is called *crappy code*. What you're asking is to have an identification and possibly resolution to both *undefined* and *undesired* behavior. The most direct, logical choice, compile with warnings as errors, was shot down with *"Then nobody could work on their own problems"*. That, sir, is *precisely* why you're where you are right now; the "we'll fix-it-later" approach. These **are** their problems; There is no [silver bullet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Silver_Bullet).

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm not disagreeing, but I'm in this spot now (I started in November). I can't just say: "our code sucks, we should fix it" because it'll just be put on a low-priority list of things to get done someday. I want to be able to show examples that are: Holy cow, this is badly broken, let's increase the priority of this! I'm one of 50 on my team, I can't unilaterally make that decision.

Comment: I concur that it isn't easy at all, and I feel your pain, believe me. I've been there, and had to be *that* guy (the squeaky wheel). But you gotta start somewhere. Aside from that, I like the concept Maxim posted below. Not sure how well it will purvey across a million-line project, but it has promise for at least eval. I think things may goto hell when external lib-functions taking pointers to the aforementioned types crop up, but for local-evals, this is *very* interesting.

Comment: @WhozCraig, His estimate of 175,000 warnings is probably not far off the mark.  It's easy from afar to say "just force all warnings to be errors", but in practice that isn't always feasible when you have deadlines to meet.

Comment: @BrianVandenberg I agree. Inheriting a mountain of dung is never a good time. I'd probably start with the most critical code and work out, a module at a time. Obviously 100,000+ warnings is going to be Stalin'esque (one death is a tragedy; a million is a statistic) to try and hit in one shot. No one will really listen. You gotta start somewhere, demonstrate value and build upon it. I really think for some things Maxims idea is an interesting one, and it earned an up-vote accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try compiling and running it with the following ugly hack:

```
#include <limits>
#include <cstdlib>

template<class T>
struct IntWrapper
{
    T value;

    template<class U>
    IntWrapper(U u) {
        if(u > std::numeric_limits<T>::max())
            std::abort();
        if(U(-1) < 0 && u < std::numeric_limits<T>::min()) // for signed U only
            std::abort();
        value = u;
    }

    operator T&() { return value; }
    operator T const&() const { return value; }
};

#define short IntWrapper<short>

int main() {
    int i = 1, j = 0x10000;
    short ii = i;
    short jj = j; // this aborts
}
```

Obviously, it may break code that passes `short` as a template argument and likely in other instances, so undefine it where it breaks the build. And you may need to add operator overloads so that the usual arithmetic works with the wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably write a plugin for gcc to detect those truncation and emit a call to a function that check the conversion is safe. You can write those plugins in [C](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/plugins) or [Python](https://gcc-python-plugin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). If you prefer to use clang, it also support writing [plugins](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangPlugins.html).

I think the easiest way to do it, would be to have the plugin convert the unsafe cast from `int` to `short` to call to a function `_convert_int_to_float_fail_if_data_loss(value)`. I'll leave it as a exercise for the reader how to write such a plugin.